# Is there a fast algorithm for generating all partitions of a set into subsets of size 2 (and one subset of size 1)?

Tags: python, list, set, python-itertools, combinatorics

As stated in the title, I'm trying to generate all partitions of a set of size n where all the subsets have size 2, and if n is uneven, there is ne singleton set. I very slightly modified some SO code for generating all partitions to get this:

```py
def partitionIntoPairs(collection):
    if len(collection) == 1:
        yield [ collection ]
        return

    first = collection[0]
    for smaller in partition2(collection[1:]):
        for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
            if len(subset):
                yield smaller[:n] + [[ first ] + subset]  + smaller[n+1:]
        yield [ [ first ] ] + smaller
```

This works, but is sadly far too slow. My second idea is to generate all pairs for a certain set using itertools.combinations, and then recursively call the function for every det without a given pair removed, but I'm guessing that's even slower. Also the implmentation is incorrect, it only returns one possible paritition, and I am unsure how to get it to return all of them:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def partitionIntoPairs2(collection):
    if not collection:
        return []
    elif len(collection) == 1:
        return [(next(iter(collection)))]
    else: 
        pairs = set(combinations(collection, 2))
        for pair in pairs: 
            collection.remove(pair[0])
            collection.remove(pair[1])
            return partition3(collection) + [pair]
```

I stumbled upon some algorithms for partitions with a given number of sets, and various implementations of algorithms generating all possible partitions, but neither of those efficiently solve my problem as far as I can see.

So, to formulate a more concrete question: If the second algorithm is a viable option, what would be the correct implementation? And of course, is there a faster way to do this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition should be viewed as a set and two partition differing only by order should be considered as the same one. So there are only 3 partitions of number set (1,2,3,4).

the number of partitions should be N!/(N/2)!/2^(N/2). Using Stirling's formula, it is approx. Sqrt(2)*(N/e)^(N/2) where e=2.71828... and very huge.

I leveraged @VirtualScooter's code and provide the recursive version of Partition, which runs faster than his itertools version (note this is not an apple-apple comparison because my Partition has no repeats).

```
import itertools
import timeit
t3 = (1, 2, 3)
t4 = (1, 2, 3, 4)
t6 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks.
        Code from Python itertools page
    """
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def partitionIntoPairs(collection):
    perms = itertools.permutations(collection)
    for p in perms:
        group = list(grouper(p, 2))
        if group[-1][-1] is None:
            group[-1] = (group[-1][0],)
        yield group

def Partition(Indexable):
    if len(Indexable)<=2:
        yield [Indexable]
    elif len(Indexable)%2==1:
        for i,x in enumerate(Indexable):
            for s in Partition(Indexable[:i]+Indexable[i+1:]):
                yield [[x]]+s
    else:
        for i,x in enumerate(Indexable):
            if i==0:
                x0=x
            else:
                for s in Partition(Indexable[1:i]+Indexable[i+1:]):
                    yield [[x0,x]]+s
def comp_timeit(collection, repeats=1_000):
    s1 = f"l1 = list(Partition({collection}))"
    s2 = f"l1 = list(partitionIntoPairs({collection}))"
    t1 = timeit.timeit(s1, globals=globals(),number=repeats)
    t2 = timeit.timeit(s2, globals=globals(),number=repeats)
    print(f"partition, {repeats:_} runs: {t1:,.4f}")
    print(f"itertools, {repeats:_} runs: {t2:,.4f}")
for p in Partition(t4):
    print(p)
comp_timeit(t3)
comp_timeit(t4)
comp_timeit(t6)
```

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer to make the generated set unique. Your algorithm is still the fastest, since the off-the-shelf algorithm needs to filter through the combinations with subset sizes > 2.

Answer (score 1):

This recursive generator function `yield`s partitions when the length of the partition is the same as the original input, and only makes recursive calls when it can either add to a subpartition in progress or retain a single subpartition (if `len(data)%2 == 1`) :

```
data = {1, 2, 3}
def partition(d, m, c = []):
   if len(l:=[j for k in c for j in k]) == len(d):
      yield c
   for i in filter(lambda x:x not in l, d):
      if not c or len(c[-1]) == m:
         yield from partition(d, m, c=c+[[i]])
      else:
         if sum(len(i) == 1 for i in c) == 1 and len(data)%2:
            yield from partition(d, m, c=c+[[i]])
         yield from partition(d, m, c=[*c[:-1], c[-1]+[i]])


print(list(partition(list(data), 2)))
```

Output:

```
[[[1], [2, 3]], [[1, 2], [3]], [[1], [3, 2]], [[1, 3], [2]], [[2], [1, 3]], [[2, 1], [3]], [[2], [3, 1]], [[2, 3], [1]], [[3], [1, 2]], [[3, 1], [2]], [[3], [2, 1]], [[3, 2], [1]]]
```

When `len(data)%2 == 0`:

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4}
print(list(partition(list(data), 2)))
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [4, 3]], [[1, 3], [2, 4]], [[1, 3], [4, 2]], [[1, 4], [2, 3]], [[1, 4], [3, 2]], [[2, 1], [3, 4]], [[2, 1], [4, 3]], [[2, 3], [1, 4]], [[2, 3], [4, 1]], [[2, 4], [1, 3]], [[2, 4], [3, 1]], [[3, 1], [2, 4]], [[3, 1], [4, 2]], [[3, 2], [1, 4]], [[3, 2], [4, 1]], [[3, 4], [1, 2]], [[3, 4], [2, 1]], [[4, 1], [2, 3]], [[4, 1], [3, 2]], [[4, 2], [1, 3]], [[4, 2], [3, 1]], [[4, 3], [1, 2]], [[4, 3], [2, 1]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `itertools`, probably faster than a recursive algorithm,
like `partition` in another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66972507/5660315). I measured 4.5s runtime for t6 in my timeit sequence like below,
versus times lower than 0.2s for `mi_partition`.

The first idea was to first list all permutations of the set, then split
each in subsets, using the `grouper` algorithm from the `itertools` document
page. Then, we cull the filler for the final odd-size subset if applicable.

As @Bing Wang points out, duplicates occur in this type of sequence. So,
instead, I called upon the `more_itertools.set_partitions` function, which
cuts down on the repetition. This also generates subsets with length greater
than 2, so these are filtered out with `itertools.filterfalse`.

```
import itertools
import timeit
import more_itertools

t3 = (1, 2, 3)
t4 = (1, 2, 3, 4)
t6 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

def mi_partition(collection):
    k = len(collection) // 2 + len(collection) % 2
    s1 = more_itertools.set_partitions(collection, k)
    if False:
        p1, p2 = itertools.tee(s1)
        print(len(list(p1)))
        s1 = p2
    return itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: any(len(y)>2 for y in x), s1)

print(list(mi_partition(t3)))
print(list(mi_partition(t4)))
```

Output:

```
[[[1], [2, 3]], [[1, 2], [3]], [[2], [1, 3]]]
[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[2, 3], [1, 4]], [[1, 3], [2, 4]]]
```

A small timing comparison with the `Partition` algorithm from
@Bing Wang's answer, suggests that their solution is faster:

```
def comp_timeit(collection, repeats=1_000):
    s3 = f"l1 = list(mi_partition({collection}))"
    s4 = f"l1 = list(Partition({collection}))"
    t3 = timeit.timeit(s3, globals=globals(),number=repeats)
    print(f"more_itertools, {repeats:_} runs: {t3:,.4f}")
    t4 = timeit.timeit(s4, globals=globals(),number=repeats)
    print(f"Partition, {repeats:_} runs: {t4:,.4f}")
comp_timeit(t3)
comp_timeit(t4)
comp_timeit(t6)
```

Output below. Note that for t3 to t4, the result list has
length 3 in both cases, while for t5, it's length 15.
It seems the `Partitions` solution is slightly faster, probably
because it does not need to filter any solutions. For t6,
set_partitions(t6, 3) generates 90 partitions, with only 15
making it into the final answer.

````
more_itertools, 1_000 runs: 0.0051
Partition, 1_000 runs: 0.0024
more_itertools, 1_000 runs: 0.0111
Partition, 1_000 runs: 0.0026
more_itertools, 1_000 runs: 0.1333
Partition, 1_000 runs: 0.0160```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your examples didn't show what does mean "all the subsets".
If you need to get all possible pairs of values in the given set just try to use set() and frozenset()

```
my_set = {1,2,3,}

res = set()
for value in my_set:
    current_set = set()
    current_set.add(value)
    for value in my_set:
        new_set = current_set.copy()
        new_set.add(value)
        res.add(frozenset(new_set))
        
if not len(my_set) % 2:
    res = [list(new_set) for new_set in res if len(new_set) > 1]
else:
    res = list(map(list, res))
print(res)
```

Comment: That wasn't my question, I'm looking to generate all partitions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of a given set of size n into subsets of size 2. If n is not even, then there may be one singleton set in the partition.